# VS show intellisense for constructors without having to delete a bracket or comma

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

I have recently moved jobs and we use TFS.  If I want to look at the intellisense for a constructor, (for code that has already been written, or dot.net code) I would normally have to delete a bracket or comma and type it again to get the constructor intellisense to appear.

This gets more annoying with TFS as it wants to check my code out, (and I don't).  Is there a shortcut key to get the intellisense up without typing in the class?

I have tried the obvious, (CTRL + space.. CTRL + ALT + Space... CTRL + J).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this a few times as well.  In my case, the fix was to go to Tools->Import and Export Settings... and choose "Reset all settings" and then restart Visual Studio.  From this point, Ctrl-Space would show the intellisense completions.  In my case, however, this would usually work and then stop working, so there may be a different problem on your machine.

This will clobber any customizations you've made (so be sure to export them if you care) but it has fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  Just to clarify, doing CTRL + Space to the left of the constructor bracket works, (I was trying inside the constructor before).

Answer (score 4):

Inside the parentheses, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to show information about the surrounding method call.